# Getting color parameter value of style attribute for all html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a iPhone project in which I want to change color theme for a given html template.

I want to get an **array with color parameter values** of **style attribute** for **all tags**.

Is there any efficient way to achieve it?

Note: elements in my template does not have id attribute. Also cannot use jquery as is not supported by iOS webview.

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of applying appropriate CSS?

Comment: It would be far easier to create multiple stylesheet then have the stylesheet switch option - Google stylesheet switcher - tons of examples out there.

Comment: Jquerry works when you call it in a proper way, like,  

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />` 

`<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` 

`<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> ` 

instead of  


`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />` 

`<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` 

`<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var colorarr=[];
$("*").each(function(){
    colorArray.push($(this).css('color'));
   });
 console.log(colorArray);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBL3D/2/)

Comment: Thanks Sridhar...can you tell me how to retrieve only those element color value who have color parameter in style attribute i.e for now it is returning rgb(0,0,0) default value for those element which does not have color parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, this can be achieved thus:

```
var colorArray=[];
$('body *').each(function(){
    colorArray.push(this.css('color'));
});
```